# Use of "Rushing me" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Is this a correct sentence grammatically:

> I have to go, My friend is rushing me

The context is - Suppose I am talking to someone over phone and my roommate is asking me 
again and again to go out, So I inform the person on phone that "I have to go, My friend is rushing me"

Is there any alternate or better way to do it ?

Comment: It's slang. It should be understood in context.

Answer (score 1):

It could fit, but I would say *nagging* or *pestering*.

*Rushing* implies "making somebody do *something they are already doing or about to do* more quickly", which may or may not fit here.

I don't see why Ronald Sole says it is slang.